# Проблема передачи массива JSON на сервер AJAX + PHP

Tags: php, ajax, json

Задача не очень сложная, получить телефоны из формы, преобразовать в массив, и отправить на сервер. Отладка консоли хрома все видно, массив создается, данные попадают в массив, но в `success` ничего не видно. В чем проблема

[image: отладка]

```
      <form id="reg"  >
         <input type="text" name="first" id="fn" >
         <input type="text" name="last"  id="ln">
         <input type="text" name="telephone" id="phone">
         <input type="text" name="telephone" >
         <button type="submit" name="post_user" id="btn_post_phones">Add</button>
      </form>
```

---

```
    var_dump(json_decode($_POST["phones"])); //PHP



    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btn_post_phones').on('click', function() {
            var arrPhones = new Array();
            $('input[name='telephone']').each(
                function() {
                    arrPhones.push($(this).val());
                });
            var data='phones='+JSON.stringify(arrPhones);
            $.ajax({
                type:     'POST',
                url:      'regist.php',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data:      data,
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                }               
            });
        });
    });
```

Comment: Вопрос в коде regist.php - что он отвечает?

Comment: `var_dump(json_decode($_POST["phones"])); //PHP` Молчит

Comment: передайте data во так:  $.ajax({
                type:     'POST',
                url:      'regist.php',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data:      arrPhones,
                success: function(resp) {
                    console.log(resp);
                }               
            }); без преобразования в строку - ajax все сделает за вас

Comment: нет, не помогло, ничего не показывает. а еще я заметил что стр. всегда обновляется, до вашего

Comment: у меня есть еще 3 запроса с ajax, они работают отлично

Comment: хм, вы забыли добавить $('#btn_post_phones').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); поэтому форма сабмитится и страница перезагружается

Comment: спасиб. Может надо больше инфо, или на этом все?  @Nikita Pimoshenko

Comment: Проверьте уходят ли данные - если задача получить их на выходе, то вам остается в regist.php только отдать нужные данные.

Comment: у меня есть такая строка ` var_dump(json_decode($_POST["phones"])); //PHP` если данные отправлены то она должна показать их? " @Nikita Pimoshenko

Comment: Да в success callback функции ajax должен придти этот дамп

Comment: Я посмотрел повнимательней, и на 99% я уверен он вообще не заходит в файл. У меня в файле regist только две строки `require_once('connect.php');`
`var_dump(json_encode($_POST["phones"]));` @Nikita Pimoshenko

Comment: Тогда уточняйте relative path для файла, вы пытаетесь вызвать php скрипт явно, но используете относительный путь(lдля web он будет строится как url + relative path). Как минимум я бы советовал включить панель разработчика в Chrome зайти в Сеть(Network) поставить фильтр XHR (это асинхронные запросы на странице) и попробовать заново послать запрос и посмотреть по какому url вы стучитесь, а потом сравнить с расположением файла на сервере. Возможно вы вообще не туда шлете и получаете 404 =)

Comment: Расшифрую например при вашей записи, если я нахожусь на странице `localhost/index.php` ajax обратиться к `localhost/index.php/regist.php` если у вас не настроены редиректы/роутинг то для базового php это значит что он пойдет искать скрипт на сервере в вашем каталоге по адресу `/index.php/regist.php`

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, то чтобы пойти от корня надо добавить `/` перед `regist.php` в вашем вызове ajax, вот так `url: '/regist.php'`

Comment: у меня еще 3 запроса `AJAX` с этим путем, и все хорошо. сейчас я посмотрел, и да он ссылается в `regist`.   вот что видно в файле `string(4) "null"`

Comment: но `success` молчит